# Arthmetic overflow error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i know this is very common issue but i tried everything still getting error

arithmetic overflow error

data in sql table for last scan time

```
    LAST_SCAN_TIME
1526640929000
1526985902000
1519248191000
1526989503000
1527011103000
1521119505000
1526993100000
1527011100000
1526903104000
1526989500000
1526640305000
1519209904000
1526640302000
1526985903000
1527040804000
1526985900000
1526982304000
0
1526985902000
1526636700000
1527011101000
1526344444000
1526985964000
1526553903000
1519248191000
1519721104000
1526989504000
1526982300000
```

I am using following query

```
select  cast(convert(int,DATEADD(second,SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME/1000,'19700101'))  as numeric) 
from SEM_AGENT SA
```

OR

```
select  DATEADD(second, SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME, '19700101') as 'Last scan time' 
from SEM_AGENT SA
```

for both queries I am getting arithmetic overflow error can you please help me out.

Last_scan_time column is bigint datatype

query iam using

```
select  DATEADD(second, SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME/1000, '19700101') as 'Last scan time' from SEM_AGENT SA 

ERROR msg Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64) 
 May  4 2015 19:11:32 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: Go here https://www.epochconverter.com/ and put those values in.  It will give you the message `Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:`  You need to use `DATEADD(millisecond, `, unless you want a date thousands of years in to the future...

Comment: Can you give the full error message? it could be either an overflow on the  conversion of SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME to INT or the resulting date value

Comment: added in edits please check

Comment: Your first query runs fine on SQL server 2017, the second fails : [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b32f1/3)

Comment: the /1000 is making the difference, not the cast/convert

Answer (score 1):

SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME is a BIGINT
and DATEADD tries to convert it to an INT that is causing the overflow

What is actually representing LAST_SCAN_TIME ? seems to me that they are milliseconds.

Try :

```
select  DATEADD(second, SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME/1000, '19700101') as 'Last scan time' from SEM_AGENT SA
```

That makes it a castable INT given the sample data you provided.

Would not recommend this solution if you don't fully control what is inserted in the column LAST_SCAN_TIME. BIGINT could still throw exceptions being converted to an INT.

Comment: whts the difference in my query and yours?

Comment: the /1000? that makes LAST_SCAN_TIME a castable INT

Comment: tht iam also adding

Comment: It is working for me with the sample data your provided. 

select  DATEADD(second, 1526903104000, '19700101')  throws error
select  DATEADD(second, 1526903104000/1000, '19700101')   does not

Comment: this does not give error select DATEADD(second, 1526903104000/1000, '19700101')  but this throws error select  DATEADD(second, SA.LAST_SCAN_TIME/1000,'19700101') as 'Last scan time' from SEM_AGENT SA what it means :(

Comment: Yes because you have data in your table that is corrupted or is not what you are expecting.  DATEADD(second, 15269031040001/1000, '19700101') will throw exception too. You should ask yourself how/where LAST_SCAN_TIME values are generated.

Comment: you mean some data is corrupted how to findout

Comment: You can try to identify those doing this :
SELECT * FROM SEM_AGENT WHERE LAST_SCAN_TIME/1000> 2147483647

, 2147483647 being the max value for an INT

Comment: there was data error in one row , excluded that it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is represented by `LAST_SCAN_TIME`?

Running the following code, for today's date '2018-05-23',:

```
select convert(bigint, getdate())
```

You can see that the output is `43241`, which does not fall within the range of the sample output that you provided.